# Tileability and computabilty

Tags: co.combinatorics, computability-theory, plane-geometry, tiling, infinite-combinatorics

Let $n>2$ be an integer. We consider $n$ pairs $(x_1,y_1),\dotsc,(x_n,y_n)$ in $\mathbb{N}^2$, and the polygon defined by drawing a straight line from $(x_k, y_k)$ to $(x_{k+1},y_{k+1})$ and from $(x_n,y_n)$ to $(x_1,x_1)$. (Lines may cross.)

We say that the points $(x_1, y_1), \ldots, (x_n,y_n)$ *define a tileable polygon*, if they are not collinear, and $\mathbb{R}^2$ can be tiled using translates of the polygon defined by these points. We let $T(n)\subseteq \mathbb{N}^{2n}$ be the set of all $n$-sets of pairs which define a tileable polygon.

**Question.** For $n>2$, is the set $T(n)\subseteq \mathbb{N}^{2n}$ computable?

**Apologies.** Despite putting in considerable effort to formulate the question, I am not sure it is written in an understandable manner.

Comment: Do you mean "translations and rotations" by "copies" ? Or do you allow axial symmetries too ?

Comment: Actually I think the set of "copies" should form a group under composition of applications. So precising what this group is could help.

Comment: Dear @Dominic: I proactively made some rather invasive changes. I think they improve the text. In particular, writing $T^{2n}$ seems unnecessary and even confusing to me, so I wrote $T(n)$. I also replaced 'copies' with 'translates'.

Comment: Whether or not a particular single polygon can tile the plane---a monohedral tiling---is not known to be undecidable. See "[Is it decidable to determine if a given shape can tile the plane?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/32538/337)."

Comment: Thanks for your comments and questions for clarifications -> I did mean translations and rotations, no axial symmetries.